# How to submit Job to flink on yarn by web ui

Tags: hadoop-yarn, apache-flink

I setup a flink cluster on yarn, and submit job by type commands related on hosts successfully.

but it is not so convenient as web ui(i have tested to submit job by web ui on fink standlone cluster).

when i click "Submit new Job" buttons , the page is as follow:

[image]

I click "here" hyperlink, it jumped to a page with a random host ip in cluster and "random" port. as we do not open all port to public network, so this page is connection refused.

[image]

I try to debug js code to find whether some config trigger this problem, and find two code fragments:

[image]

[image]

It seems like this page must not function well with flink on yarn.

So, can i submit job to flink on yarn by web ui? and how?

Answer (score 0):

As the message states YARN proxy, which you are seeing does not allow file uploads. If you really wanna upload jobs via web-ui on yarn, you can find out the real ip of the jobmanager and go to that ip directly(without yarn proxy).

There are some issues though with the approach. You have to have access to that node, which is usually not the case on yarn. (Which most probably you are hitting).

Answer (score 0):

Flink on yarn has two modes: session and per-job. If you need to submit via web-ui, you must first create a yarn-session and enter session web-ui to submit, but per-job should not be submitted via web-ui Submitted